# PHP how to pass a variable-length function parameters to another variable length function?

Tags: php, variadic-functions

I have two functions with an optional amount of variables:

```
function getTexts()
{
  $this->printTextToDashboard();
}

function printTextToDashboard()
{
  $args = func_get_args();
  $argsNum = count($args);
  for($i=0; $i < $argsNum; $i++)
  {
    echo "This is the $i text: "."<br />".$args[$i]."<br />";
  }
}
```

For instance I want to call getTexts like this:

```
getTexts($name, $lastname, $email);
```

I know it has something to do with `user_func_*` , but I'm unable to implement it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
function getTexts()
{
    call_user_func_array(array($this, 'printTextToDashboard'), func_get_args());
}
```

Comment: or, in php 5.6 (and above): `$this->printTextToDashboard(...func_get_args());`